# How to check, also, if var is defined at Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this code at Twig template:

```
{% if form_action is empty or form_action is null or form_action is not defined %}
    {% set form_action = '' %}
{% endif %}
```

But when I load the page I got this error message:

> Variable "form_action" does not exist in AppBundle::pdone.html.twig at line 1

How do I check also if variable is set? Is not the condition enough? Any advice?

Comment: you may set default value insteed {{ form_action | default('') }}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of your statement is not correct. Usually this should be enough:

```
{% if form_action is not defined %}
```

to see if a `variable` has a value:

```
{% if form_action %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `is defined`

```
{% if form_action is defined %}
 {# Do your stuff here #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: OP is using the test `defined` just not in the right order